# window.onscroll mobile equivalent?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On desktop browsers, `window.scroll` fires off continuously as the browser is scrolled. However, in my testing on iOS and Android Chrome, it only fires when the scrolling has finished.

I tried [`touchmove`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchmove) but that had the same behavior - only firing when the movement finished.

Is there an event on mobile devices that fires continuously, like a desktop browser?

Comment: touchmove should fire on every move. Could you show us some code, maybe there's a small devil hidden somewhere ?

Comment: It fires on every move, just not during the move. Specifically, it fires once per actual physical touch once the finger is removed from the device. I am having trouble finding a site like jsfiddle.net that works well with mobile to get a sample up and running. Really, it is a trivial sample ... wiring up the event and `console.log` a message in the event.

Comment: use a canvas, clearRect and fillText !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently there's no way to get passed it because the "iOS  devices freeze the DOM manipulation during the scroll event"!

Take a look at this link the scroll start section! http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.0/docs/api/events.html

Comment: It looks like it is even larger than just DOM manipulation. I tried using `setInterval` on `touchstart` and once I started to move/scroll the page, the intervals stopped firing. Maybe there is something wrong with my test, but it seems like all JavaScript execution is halted during scrolling in iOS.

Comment: Seems like it, but If you specify what is it that you're trying to achieve maybe a workaround or an idea would come up!

Answer (score 4):

Might want to take a look at this site:

http://andyshora.com/mobile-scroll-event-problems.html

It helps explains why your going to be banging you head against a wall.